# Angular-MVC Moved Angular Controller to seperate file.. How to I load @Model now?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Angular with MVC

I wrote everything on the html page in

@Model has the model data that I'm using for my $scope's main model.

```
<script>
    var runApp = angular.module('runApp', []);
    runApp.controller('DistanceController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.running = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    $scope.errorMessage = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode((@TempData["ErrorMessage"])));
    ....
}
</script>
```

This worked find but now that I've moved my controller to a JS file I can't call @Html or @Model from a stand alone JS file.

On page load the page already has the @Model that I need, making an AJAX call for it wouldn't return the particular model I want to work with.

Current JS file

```
        var runApp = angular.module('runApp', []);
        runApp.controller('DistanceController', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.running = {};
        $scope.errorMessage =null;
        ....
    }
```

I somehow need to set the model.

This has to be easy for somebody out there I bet. But I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in this way on you html page (MVC View Page) add that:

```
angular.module('runApp').factory('dataBoot', function(){

   running = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
   errorMessage = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode((@TempData["ErrorMessage"])));

  retrun {
    running: running,
     errorMessage: errorMessage

  }


});
```

after that you can inject dataBoot into your controller and have access to running and errorMessage in that way:

```
runApp.controller('DistanceController', function($scope, $http, dataBoot) {

        $scope.running = dataBoot.running;
        $scope.errorMessage =dataBoot.errorMessage;
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the beginner question but.. is app.factory a var?

would it be like this

<script>
var app.factory('dataBoot', function(){
   running = @Html.Raw(..);
   errorMessage = @Html.Raw(...);

   return {
       running: nunning,
       errorMessage: errorMessage
   }
}
</script>

Comment: ahh that App.. okay just a sec.. let me test this out

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the ng-init directive and the property you use will be available in the scope for that particular element

```
<div ng-controller="DistanceController" ng-init="running = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))">
    ...
</div>
```